# Unable to get selected id in kartik-v dependent-dropdown

Tags: php

I just tried using kartik-v's dependent-dropdown jquery library. It kept on posting the text value of the option selected to the php script. However, I am not using the Yii Framework. I am just using my normal PHP.

Here is my code. 
I want it to submit the actual id of the category selected instead of something like "Home", or "Sweet"

```html
    <select id="cat-id" class="form-control">
        <option id="">Select ...</option>
        <option id="1">Home</option>
        <option id="2">Sweet</option>
        <option id="3">Gather</option>
        <!-- other options -->
    </select>

    <!-- HTML Markup (Child # 1) -->
    <select id="subcat-id" class="form-control">
        <option id="">Select ...</option>
        <!-- other options -->
    </select>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Child # 1
            $("#subcat-id").depdrop({
                url: 'getSubcat.php',
                depends: ['cat-id']
            });
        })
    </script>
```

I have tried adding this to the script

```js
$('#cat-id').on('depdrop:change', function(event, id, value, count, textStatus, jqXHR) {
console.log(id);
console.log(value);
});
```

but none of these seems to work...

Please help..
Pointers or tips...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally fixed it. The problem is with the options tag having ids!
Instead of id="whatever", it should be value="whatever".

Every part of the code aside the additional code I copied from the docs is fine...